# advice on using .className, currently doesn't work within my loop?

Tags: javascript

Ive created a loop to assign the class 'last' to every fifth element but for some reason .className doesn't seem to work. I originally used .class but ie7 and ie8 error out at this. Can anyone advise how I can resolve this?

**JS Snippet**

```
success: function(response) {
                    var source = $("#calendar-template").html(),
                            template = Handlebars.compile(source),
                            gameHTML = '';

                    for (var i = 0, gameLength = response.data.games.length; i < gameLength; i++){
                        var thisGame = response.data.games[i];
                        console.log(thisGame);
                        thisGame.className = ((i+1) % 5 == 0) ? 'last' : '';

                        gameHTML += template(thisGame);
                    }

                    instance.selectors.dateWrapper.append(gameHTML);

                    deferredObject.resolve();

                    instance.displayGames();
                },
```

**Response**

```
data: Object
games: Array[18]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
...
```

Cheers

Comment: Where does `response.data.games` come from?

Comment: There's no jquery in this, and we don't know what response.data.games is?

Comment: response.data.games is a json response and this loop is used to template the data as well as work out the 5th element and add the class

Comment: I don't understand the question. A jsfiddle would certainly help

Comment: Are you sure `thisGame` is DOM element? I guess you have a HTML string, so of course `className` is not its property.

Comment: You probably need to do var el = getElementById(thisGame); if your data comes from a ajax request. It will never contain any DOM elements, on which you can set something like a class, only an id.

Comment: no thisGame = each object inside the games array which is then templated using handebars

Comment: You are right. `domElement.className = "YourClassHere"` is a correct way of changing/adding a class to a DOM element. The problem is somewhere else. Are you sure `response.data.games` do represent DOM elements? Or else, what do `response.data.games` represent?

Comment: response.data.games is the array inside json response which is then looped through to template each object

Comment: Just post an example of response!..

Comment: Since `response.data.games` is a JSON response, you should first create DOM elements from the JSON response.

Comment: but how come using .class works but .className doesn't?

Comment: oh I see, its because I'm trying to add a class to an object and not an element?

Comment: yes. the handlebars library will add the class attribute to some DOM element when `template(thisGame)` is invoked. please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could understand that you are using the **handlebars** library.

`response.data.games` is a object that contains the context for existent HTML content. The call `template(thisGame)` will  substitute some parts of the `#calendar-template` element. Probably you have a `{{class}}` as handlebar expression somewhere. So, YOU SHOULD use `thisGame.class` and not `thisGame.className`.

Remember that you are not messing with a DOM element but with a handlebars context object.

Comment: yeah this is completely correct, i totally confused myself with this. i used {{class}} in my template but then .class threw an error in IE then I changed to .classVal and update {{classVal}} and all is good now. Slight confusion on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do var el = getElementById(thisGame); if your data comes from a ajax request. It will never contain any DOM elements, on which you can set something like a class, only an id.